# ubuntu черный экран

Tags: ubuntu

Я знаю, что по этому вопросу куча инфы в гугле, но у меня черный экран 30с, а потом все норм.

Компьютер мощный, не хотелось бы загружать Ubuntu за 30c

Как это исправить, а то уже бесит?(

Comment: Обычный ответ на это — "зачем вы вообще пытаетесь загружать систему?" Загрузили один раз после сборки компьютера — и пусть он работает или спит до следущего апгрейда железа.

Comment: всм, я не собираюсь аппать...

Comment: Значит пусть работает вечно. Если вы загружаете убунту, значит вы её когда-то выключали — а зачем выключали, если можно не выключать? :)

Comment: А вообще надо системные логи изучать, какая служба в какой момент времени запускается

Comment: Наивные комменты о ненадобности выключения, имхо. Я молчу о том, что далеко не каждая программа способна адекватно восстановиться после гибернации, но лично я банально не могу спать когда компьютер мигает в темноте всеми своими диодами как гирлянда. Кроме того, у меня лично ещё и колонки издают очень слабый, но раздражающий шум, если их не отключить от питания. Ну и роутеру по ночам также нет никакой необходимости греться. Гораздо проще выдернуть всё целиком из розетки! А по поводу вопроса - логи в студию!

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf гибернация не нужна, компьютер прячется, роутер не греется, колонки выключаются от сети кнопкой на корпусе. Разве что электричество экономить)

Comment: @andreymal не, ну если гибернация не нужна и речь о том, чтобы его **совсем** не выключать, то тут нужен либо очень слабый компьютер, не нуждающийся в охлаждении, либо какая-то очень экзотическая система охлаждения, вроде водяной, чтобы спокойно спать рядом. не знаю как вы, а я когда круглые сутки слышу вентилятор, у меня шарики за ролики едут.

Answer (score 0):

`systemd-analyse plot > boot.svg && xdg-open boot.svg`

И смотрите сколько, как быстро и какие сервисы, которыми вы возможно не пользуетесь, запускаются при старте.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, будет возможность проверю!